# I'm to make an interior [512][512] but it keeps on crashing

Tags: c

I'm trying to fill this array completely full with 3 bits of data each

`unsigned long int array2[512][512];`

but my program just keeps on crashing.
does anyone know the solution?

Comment: If that is a local array, you perhaps break the stack. You can allocate the memory dynamically.

Comment: It's like the site name says: stack overflow!

Comment: You are trying to put `512 * 512 * sizeof(unsigned long)` bytes on the stack.  That is roughly 2MB.  Typical stack space is around 1MB.  You have run out of stack-space. ***StackOverflow!***